# Getting keys of array in Tcl C code

Tags: c, arrays, tcl

I am trying to access and manipulate Tcl associative arrays in C. I know that Tcl_GetVar2 reads the values, but how do I get access to the array's keys? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no convenient C API for listing the keys of an associative array (and that's actually true even if you were using the Tcl's internal interfaces; the issue is that the nature of what is really in the array is deeply non-trivial). The simplest method is to use `Tcl_Eval` or one of its related functions to call `array names`; something like this C function would wrap it up nicely (though you still need to be careful to manage the result lifetime, etc.):

```c
Tcl_Obj *GetArrayKeys(
    Tcl_Interp *interp,
    const char *arrayName) {
  Tcl_Obj *script = Tcl_NewStringObj("array names", -1);
  int result;

  Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(NULL, script, Tcl_NewStringObj(arrayName, -1));
  Tcl_IncrRefCount(script);
  result = Tcl_EvalObjEx(interp, script, TCL_EVAL_DIRECT);
  Tcl_DecrRefCount(script);
  if (result != TCL_OK)
    return NULL;
  return Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
}
```